# who is calling to the run() method

Tags: java

```
 package com.nacre.test7;

public class TestDaemon {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyDaemon dt=new MyDaemon();
        if(dt.isDaemon()){

            System.out.println(dt+"is demon thread");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(" main thread is ending.");
        }

    }
}


package com.nacre.test7;

public class MyDaemon implements Runnable{

    Thread thrd;

    MyDaemon() {

        thrd=new Thread(this);
        thrd.setDaemon(true);
        thrd.start();
    }

    public boolean isDaemon(){

        return thrd.isDaemon();
    }

    public void run() { 
        try { while(true) {
            System.out.print(".");
            //Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("MyDaemon interrupted."); 
            }
    }

}
```

In the above 2 class I have given breakpoint to each line in the program.I started debugging in eclipse editor and what I saw the control flow is ...........coming back to this below code after executing thrd.start() method of MyDaemon class

```
if(dt.isDaemon()){

            System.out.println(dt+"is demon thread");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(" main thread is ending.");
        }
```

and noway the control is going to this below part

```
public void run() { 
        try { while(true) {
            System.out.print(".");
            Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("MyDaemon interrupted."); 
            }
```

What I knew is that when start() method is called , concurrently jvm calls run method by creating a new thread , my doubt is that why I am unable to see the execution of the run method while debugging 
and how I am getting the following output

com.nacre.test7.MyDaemon@152b6651is demon thread
.......... main thread is ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to

**how I am getting the following output
com.nacre.test7.MyDaemon@152b6651is demon thread .......... main thread is ending.**

The program is behaving perfectly fine. You cannot accept the main thread to be alive if the only thread it starts is a Daemon thread. Please read the source code / java doc of the Thread class.

Moreover, to your other question **my doubt is that why I am unable to see the execution of the run method while debugging and**

The run method execution is shown in the debug mode as below:
[image]

Comment: the pics that you have given is showing public void run() method but noway it is showing control is going inside to the run() method like other statement in the class.......... thats what I am asking.

Comment: You will not be able to see that. Reason The main thread dies as soon as the last statement is executed. So now you have lost the debugger.


If you want to see the control in the run method, increase the sleep time to 1,00,000 milliseconds and then put a debug point in the run method. It works

Comment: Moreover, the moment main thread wakes up it will die and then you will again loose the debugger. The debugger is not available for hte daemon thread execution

Comment: ok I got it ...........my other doubt is ,"The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads." I copied it from api ,what is the meaning of it............is it saying ........the jvm will stop work if all the thread are demon thread........if no correct correct me.

Comment: Below is the snippet from the java source code :

When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs: 

The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place. 
All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

Comment: is the main thread will die after a new demon thread is created  ?

Comment: yeah ... the main thread dies if there is nothing much to do in the main method.

Answer (score 2):

`Java Virtual Machine`.

*When you create `Thread` object and call `start()` on it gives the `JVM` a special instruction to create java thread,Here `JVM`does some deep magic that we cannot do in normal Java code. Via native calls it creates a new thread  and causes the new thread to call the `run()` method.*

According to [Thread#start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start)

> Calling start() causes this thread to begin execution; **the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread**.

Answer (score 0):

> who is calling to the `run()` method?

The `thrd.start()` call in the `MyDaemon` constructor is causing it to happen.

In `MyDaemon` you instantiate a `Thread` object and pass it `this` as an argument.  When a `Thread` object is started, it calls *its* `run()` method, and the default behaviour of the `Thread.run()` object is to call `run()` on its `Runnable` ... if one was supplied.

So:

1. the `MyDaemon` constructor creates a `Thread` object
2. the `MyDaemon` constructor calls `thrd.start()`
3. `thrd.start()` starts the new thread with a new stack
4. the new thread calls `thrd.run()`
5. `thrd.run()` calls `run()` on the `MyObject` instance

Note that steps 1 through 3 happen on the parent thread, and steps 4 through 5 happen on the child thread, either before or after the `start()` call returns in the parent thread.